# How to use style css files in Next.js?

Tags: css, next.js

I'm new to Next.js.

Although I declared css files in _app.tsx, some of styles defined in the css files are not working.
Some of styles use images imported from 'public/images' and this are not imported neither.
Please help me find out what is wrong with this. Do I have to change the folder structure?
The version of Next.js is "13.1.1".

Thanks in advance!!

I'm working on a project with below folder structures.

- public

  - fonts
  - images
- src

  - pages
  - styles

    - global.css
    - layout.css

My _app.tsx file looks like

```
import '@/styles/layout.css';
import '@/styles/common.css';

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

am also new to Nextjs , turned out you can't use regular CSS files, you should use  `CSS modules`.

you need to rename each CSS file 'except global' to end with `.module.css` instead of `.css`
then you need to import the file in the component you want to style : `import styles from 'style/file.module.css'`

to style an element create a class in the CSS file:
 `.paragraph{ color:green }`

and then use it in the component:

```
        <p className={styles.paragraph}>I am styled with CSS modules</p>
```

[Ref](https://blog.logrocket.com/best-styling-options-nextjs/)!

there is a standard CSS framework called Tailwindcss you should try it

Answer (score 0):

Rename your CSS file as layout.module.css. Use .module.css extension in your CSS files. Refer [nextjs documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support) for further references.